# what is that I'm missing to run jersey 2 web service?

Tags: java, apache, jersey, jersey-2.0

I created a dynamic java project and added this dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then i created the App class like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/test")
public class App extends ResourceConfig {
    public App() {
        this.packages("com.test.ul");
    }
}
```

and in the same package as the App class is in, i created this:

```
@Path("restaurantAPI")
public class RestaurantAPI {

    @Path("/get")
    @GET
    public Response getRequest(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return Response.ok(id).build();
    }

}
```

I run my server, and I call this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/ULTestServer/test/restaurantAPI/get?id=3
```

but I get error 404

What Am I missing please ? (I always do that and it used to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
jersey-container-servlet-core
```

to

```
jersey-container-servlet
```

The reason is that the latter has the [required component](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html)<sup>1</sup> that allows for discovering your application without web.xml, in replace for `@ApplicationPath`. This is part of the servlet 3 pluggability mechanism.

The first dependency is use for non servlet 3.0 containers, where the use would *have* to use a web.xml to register the Jersey servlet.

---

<sub>1 - [Here is the implementation](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.23.1/containers/jersey-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java)</sub>